# Unreal material rendered in Viewport but not in Details Panel (plugindev)

Tags: c++, unreal

I am writing a plugin that parses StaticMeshComponents of a blueprint and switches their material.

My problem is that everything works fine (and debugging values confirm it) except that once the operation is done, the mesh has the correct material rendered in BP’s Viewport but not in its Details Panel (nor in BP’s thumbnail or when I’m dragging it into my level).

Any idea of what may cause this bug to happen ?

Thanks in advance !

[Workflow Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2dmI.png)

Tried calling all kind of "UpdateNotification" functions (bp->Modify, staticMesh->PostEditChange,...) and using StaticMesh::CreateAndSetMaterialInstanceDynamicFromMaterial() but the result is the same.